# Threshold image with trackbar

Tags: c#, picturebox, threshold, trackbar

I am trying to set the threshold of an image at runtime. Currently my code looks like:

```
ImageAttributes imageAttr = new ImageAttributes();
imageAttr.SetThreshold(kryptonTrackBar1.Value / 100);

System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(pictureBox3.Image);
Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 0, 0,
                 bmp.Width, bmp.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttr);
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

`picturebox3` contains the black and white image. The problem is inside the `imageAttr.SetThreshold(kryptonTrackBar1.Value / 100);` line.

My trackbar max is 100 and min 0.
So I should end up with numbers like 0.07 and so on while scrolling the trackbar, but the trackbar only returns the value of 0 and 1! 1 if I scroll all the way to the right!

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
imageAttr.SetThreshold((float)kryptonTrackBar1.Value / 100.0f);
```

Comment: Thats it!! thank your very much! i am new to c#(vb.net background).

Comment: Yes. You tried dividing integer value 1 - 100 by integer value 100, which results always in 0 or 1. They must be casted to floats so that .NET understands you need a floating point division.